# How would I go about inserting data into one-to-many(must) relation, psycopg2/python in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, entity-relationship, psycopg2

Using psycopg2/python how would I go about inserting data if I'd have something like from this img.

GRUPA (class GROUP) must contain one or more STUDENT's

How to fill them up and how to add them after, I can't add a GROUP without a student and I can't add a STUDENT w/o a GROUP.

Must it be a transaction/deferrable-constraints to add them in batch/together just to create GROUP?

What options do I have, how would you do it?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have an `id_group` in the `students` table.  It doesn't really make sense.

But if you do, make it null-able.  Then you can:

- Add a student into the table with a `null` value for `id_group`.
- Add a group, with the student.
- Update the students table with the value for the group.

However, you might also want to relax your requirements.  For instance, perhaps a group could have no students.  It wouldn't be a very active group, but the group can exist as a separate entity.

In fact, a more natural way to represent this data would be:

- A `students` table with one row per student and no group reference.
- A `groups` table with one row per group and no student reference.
- A `studentGroups` table with one row per student in each group.